# Cannot convert value of type 'UILabel!' to expected argument type 'String' in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need help on this error. I cannot convert value of type `UILabel!` to expected argument type `String` in swift.

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class HeroViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heroImgVw: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var quirkLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var characterBtn: UIButton!

    let heroes = Heroes()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        generateRandomCharacter()
    }


    @IBAction func characterBtnDidTouch(_ sender: Any) {

        generateRandomCharacter()
        let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: nameLbl)
        utterance.rate = 0.4
        utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
    }
```

Comment: change     let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: nameLbl) to     let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: nameLbl.text)

Answer (score 0):

```
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: nameLbl.text)
```

Because, What you want is your label's text and not the label itself